# Max not populating in Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have been able to get max to populate correctly but this has caused min to populate as zero. The only time this will show correct is if zero is in fact one of the integers the user inputs. For example if I choose to input 4 integers such as 7,4,2,6. The output will show Min = 0 and Max = 7. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this would be?

```
# Reinitialize counters, reload array address for printing
li $t0, 0               # Initilize array index value back to 0
li $t3, 0               # Initial counter back to zero

# Reinitialize counters, reload array address for min/max calculations
la $t0,array            # Load address of array back -> t0
lw $t1,count            # t1 = count, exit loop when it goes to 0
lw $t5,($t0)            # t5 = min = a[0] (initialization)
lw $t6,($t0)            # t6 = max = a[0] (initialization)

add $t0,$t0,4           # move pointer ahead to next array element a[1]
add $t1,$t1,-1          # decrement counter to keep in step with array   

loop:   lw $t4,($t0)                # Load next array(t0) element -> t4
        bge $t4,$t5,notMin          # IF array element is >= min go to notMin
        move $t5,$t4                # Move array element t4 -> min      
        j notMax

notMin: ble $t4,$t6,notMax          # IF array element t4 is <= max go to notMax
        move $t6,$t4                # ELSE Move array element t4 -> max

notMax: add $t1,$t1,-1              # Decrement counter by 1
        add $t0,$t0,4               # Increment index to point to next word
        bnez $t1,loop               # Loop back to top if count != 0

la $a0,p1               # Load address of output string -> a0
li $v0,4                # Load call code for display a string [4] -> v0
syscall                 # System call to display "The Minimum Number is: "

move $a0,$t5            # Display the minimum number 
li $v0,1                # Load the call code to display an integer[1] -> v0
syscall                 # System call to print integer

la $a0,p2               # Load address of output string -> a0
li $v0,4                # Load call code for display a string [4] -> v0
syscall                 # System call to display "The Maximum Number is: "

move $a0,$t6            # Display the maximum number 
li $v0,1                # Load the call code to display an integer[1] -> v0
syscall                 # System call to print integer

# Move to new line for readability  
la $a0,endl             # Load new line character -> a0
li $v0,4                # Load call code to print a string[4] -> v0
syscall                 # System call to print new line character

li $v0,10               # End Of Program
syscall                 # Call to system 


.data
prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter Number of Integers :"    # Initial Prompt to set array size
intPrompt:  .asciiz "Enter an Integer: "            # Prompt for each int in the array  
title:      .asciiz "\nArray: "                     # Output String of "Array:"
comma:      .asciiz ", "                            # Output of comma
count:      .word 15                                # Loop counter for min/max
p1:         .asciiz "\nThe Minimum Number is: "     # Minimum Number String
p2:         .asciiz "\nThe Maximum Number is: "     # Maximum Number String
endl:       .asciiz "\n"                            # New line character
array:      .word 60                                # 15 words
```

Very New to Assembly, have an array, need to find min and max and display, min is fine, can't figure out where my max is going wrong, any help is much appreciated. I have only posted the actual loop portion as well as the data section for clarity.

```
# Reinitialize counters, reload array address for min/max calculations
li $t0, 0               # Initilize array index value back to 0
la $t0,array            # Load address of array back -> t0

lw $t1,count            # t1 = count, exit loop when it goes to 0
lw $t5,0($t0)           # t5 = min = a[0] (initialization)
lw $t6,0($t0)           # t6 = max = a[0] (initialization)

add $t0,$t0,4           # move pointer ahead to next array element a[1]
add $t1,$t1,-1          # decrement counter to keep in step with array   

loop:   lw $t4,($t0)                # t4 = next element in array
        bge $t4,$t5,notMin          # if array element is >= min goto notMin
        move $t5,$t4                # min = a[i]
        j notMax

notMin: ble $t4,$t6,notMax          # if array element is <= max goto notMax
        move $t6,$t4                # max = a[i]

notMax: add $t1,$t1,-1              # t1 -- -> counter --
    add $t0,$t0,4                   # increment counter to point to next word
    bnez $t1,loop

    la $a0,p1           # Load address of output string -> a0
    li $v0,4            # Load call code for display a string [4] -> v0
    syscall             # System call to display "The Minimum number is "

    move $a0,$t5        # Display the minimum number 
    li $v0,1            # Load the call code to display an integer[1] -> v0
    syscall             # System call to print integer

    la $a0,p2           # Load address of output string -> a0
    li $v0,4            # Load call code for display a string [4] -> v0
    syscall             # System call to display "The Maximum number is "

    move $a0,$t6        # Display the maximum number 
    li $v0,1            # Load the call code to display an integer[1] -> v0
    syscall             # System call to print integer

    la $a0,endl         # Display "cr/lf"
    li $v0,4            # a0 = address of message
    syscall             # v0 = 4 which indicates display a string

    li $v0,10           # End Of Program
    syscall             # Call to system

.data
array:      .word 60                            # 15 words
count:      .word 15                            # Loop counter for min/max
p1:         .asciiz "\nThe Minimum number is "  # Minimum Number String
p2:         .asciiz "\nThe Maximum number is "  # Maximum Number String
endl:       .asciiz "\n"                        # New line character
```

Comment: `.word 60 ` does not allocate 15 words. It allocates a single word with value 60.

Comment: Thank you Jester, my understanding was that each byte was 4 in size, thus (15 * 4) = 60. I will look back over the material covering this for a better understanding.

Comment: one bit = 0/1. One byte = 8 bits (when you interpret 8 bits as unsigned integer in common way, you can have values from 0 to 255 stored in byte). One word (on MIPS! On other platforms may differ!) = 4 bytes = 32 bits (when interpreted as unsigned integers, can store values from 0 to (2^32-1) ). The `.word 60` will compile as four bytes of memory: `3C 00 00 00` (hexadecimal values). You did probably want `.space 60` => reserving space for 15 words. But then you may as precaution add also line `.align 2` ahead of `array:` label. In your case the `array:` will be aligned, it's first in `.data`.

Comment: Thank you Ped7g, I have made a little progress on this as well as a slight step backwards. I will edit original post with new portions.